# Changing a configuration file and complex comment manipulation

Tags: sed, comments, configuration-files

I want to be able to change specific settings in a configuration file, which includes removing the comment code (`;`) that comment out those settings. Furthermore, I want to preserve real comments. That means that

```
some_setting=0
```

or

```
;some_setting=0
```

would both become

```
some_setting=9
```

But it also means that

```
some_setting=0    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
```

or

```
;some_setting=0    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
```

would be

```
some_setting=9    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
```

I'd also want to leave

```
;Idle talk about some_setting=
```

alone.

I seem to be able to achieve almost all of this with

```
sed -e 's/^\s*;\?\s*some_setting\s*=.*\(;\)\?/some_setting=9  \1/'
```

but the problem is the real comments get stripped out of lines that have `some_setting`. Notice that I've made allowances for there to be whitespace around a lot of these tokens.

I've looked at using `awk` for this, but it seems the best bet is `sed`.

I'm using GNU sed 4.2.2 on a Debian 8.3 for this.

Comment: Is this correct: if a lines starts with `some_setting=` or `;some_setting=`, it should be modified to start with `some_setting=9`, and everything else shouldn't be touched?

Comment: "Everything else" meaning other lines should be untouched, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I used this as test input:

```
some_setting=0
;some_setting=0
some_setting=0    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
;some_setting=0    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
;Idle talk about some_setting=
```

Using this command:

```
$ sed -r 's/^;?(some_setting=)[^[:space:]]*(.*)/\19\2/' infile
some_setting=9
some_setting=9
some_setting=9    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
some_setting=9    ;an honest-to-goodness comment
;Idle talk about some_setting=
```

So a line starting with an optional `;` followed by `some_setting=` and whatever non-space characters come after it is replaced with a line starting with `some_setting=9`; the rest of the line stays the same.

Comment: That's pretty good. What's `:space:`? I've never seen that before. I didn't want to assume that the data for the setting was w/out spaces, but now that I think about it, I also didn't consider the possibility that a semi-colon would be part of the setting. For instance `some_setting='a setting w/a ; in it'    ;followed by a comment.`

Comment: @Opux `[:space:]` is a "POSIX character class". The same as `\s`, but more portable.

If settings can be quoted and contain a semicolon, that's still possible, but gets more cumbersome. Do such settings exist? If yes, you can update the question, if you want to.